# The same source line is green for a test suite, but white for the other test suite in Jacoco report?

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, test-coverage

I have two test suite T1 and T2. As shown in the pictures, for T1, the line 55 `private abstract class SafeNotifier {` is not marked as red, green or yellow. But for T2, it is green.

So I have two questions:

1. What does it mean when a class declaration line is green? I think it is not executable?
2. I thought all the executable lines in the report should be either red, green or yellow. Am I correct? If yes, how to interpret that the line 55 is white for T1 but green for T2?

Thanks!

[image] [image]

---

I also see a strange case where T2 covers line 163 but for T1 line 163 is white. How to interpret this?
[image]